# Bash: How to create variables from array of strings?

Tags: bash

I have the file "Testfile", whit a register in every line, each register having some fields:

```
foo1=32=test01=30/03/2012 10:03 p.m
foo2=54=test02=30/03/2012 10:05 p.m
foo3=912=test03=30/03/2012 10:08 p.m
```

("=" is the field delimiter)

I read the first field for every register and store them in an array, and the same for the second field of every register:

```
NAMES=(`cut -f1 -d'=' Testfile`)
VALUES=(`cut -f2 -d'=' Testfile`)
```

That gives me two arrays like these: (foo1 foo2 foo3) and (32 54 912)

Is it possible to dynamically create variables named foo1 foo2 and foo3, and assign them their respective values?

I could do:

```
foo1 = ${VALUES[0]}
foo2 = ${VALUES[1]}
foo3 = ${VALUES[2]}
```

But I want to get the names of the variables dynamically, regarding the names that I've got from the file.

Comment: Give an example of exactly what is in 'Testfile'.  As question is now, answers are likely to be right but cannot be verified.

Comment: sorry, you're right, I've just edited to add an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat Testfile 
foo1=35
foo2=54
foo3=912

for v in $(cat Testfile); do declare "$v"; done

echo $foo1 
35

echo $foo2 
54
```

that will work if lines in file looks exact like this:

```
var=val
```

and here is a version that works with spaces:

```
cat Testfile
foo1 = 35
foo2 = 54
foo3 = 912

while read line; do
    if [ -z "$line" ]; then continue; fi
    var=$(echo $line | cut -d'=' -f1)
    val=$(echo $line | cut -d'=' -f2)
    declare "$(echo $var)=$(echo $val)"
done < Testfile

echo $foo1 
35
```

Comment: The loop that handles spaces won't quite work, as the spaces will cause word-splitting. `while read s; do ...; done < Testfile` should work better.

Comment: In the case with only two fields it works fine, but if I have more (like in the example I've added) it has some issues (don't know if I'm right, but it seems that its trying to declare every field as a variable, and since some fields doesn't fit the correct syntax for variable naming, it throws some errors)

Comment: well, updated to support multiple `=` syntax. also, it is echoing `var` and `val` to get rid of eventual spaces.

Comment: It works now! and its a very clear way to do it also. Thanks slivu

Answer (score 3):

If the values have no whitespace (as in the example) or are wrapped in quotes, this is as simple as "sourcing" the file.

```
source Testfile
```

This will basically "run" the file, which in this case simply defines some variables and returns.

Comment: Thanks. It works if I just declare and assign variables in the file, but not if I have many consecutive fields per line.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
NAMES_VALUES=($(sed 's/\(\S*\)\s*\(\S*\)\s*.*/\1=\2/' Testfile))
eval "${NAMES_VALUES[@]}"
```

EDIT:

If the file format uses `=` as delimiters:

```
NAMES_VALUES=($(sed 's/^\([^=]*=[^=]*\)=.*/\1/' Testfile))
eval "${NAMES_VALUES[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, but whith more than two fields, it takes everything after the first "=" as the value. How could I discard the fields after the second "=", to get only the second field as the value of the variable?